# How can I add row of components to a GUI when a button has been pressed?

Tags: sql, codenameone

I'm putting together an app where a user can record information about like a sale of an unknown number of items in a business. My question is based on recording the quantity, name, individual price and total price of each item sold in a sale. I've already coded a java computer program where I have a table available on the GUI, the user records the information of one item in a table and if they need more rows there is a button which can be pressed each time a new row is needed. I'm wondering:
A) is there a table component I can use in Codenameone on the GUI and
B) can I have the same concept of pressing a button in order to add a new row to the table?

If this isn't possible, because I've had no luck while researching this topic, does anyone have any suggestions of how I can record an unknown number of items for a sale on one GUI page?

UPDATE:

Here is the code which is in the method that adds a new row to the table container.

```
 protected void onSale_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    Container tbl = findTbl(c);
    TextField txt = new TextField();
    ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
    TextField txt2 = new TextField();
    tbl.addComponent(txt);
    tbl.addComponent(cmb);
    tbl.addComponent(txt2);
    tbl.animateLayout(300);

}
```

The button does add the new row but it changes the table layout by resizing all the components and some aren't visible on the screen. I have used the setWidth() method after declaring each component in hope of changing the size of the component but with no luck. How can I solve this problem, so that the new components are the same size as the very first row of components in the table?
And also, after a random number of rows have been filled in with information, i'd like to read this info and save it to a database. I've done this in a computer java program in a JTable and stored the data into a 2D array and then read from the array into the database. Is this method applicable for the container above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "table components" specifically Table, TableLayout & GridLayout.

Adding a row to each of them is somewhat different, lets assume you use a TableLayout container with the container being tbl and having 2 columns:

```
tbl.addComponent(cmp1);
tbl.addComponent(cmp2);
tbl.animateLayout(300);
```

Adds both components and animates them into place.

Comment: Hi Shai, I've done so and when pressing the button it adds the new row of components, however i'm still having some trouble. I've updated the question, please refer to it if you can, all help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Is the table scrollable? Is the parent form scrollable? Which layout is the table placed in and how would you want everything to behave? You might be better served for some use cases with form.animateHierarchy() rather than animating the table (depending on your scrolling/hierarchy choices).

Comment: Yes i've made the table scrollable just so i can see all the textfields however when the form opens, i have one row with 3 components in it and they are sized specifically so that they fit on the screen without scrolling. I wish to keep these sizes for each column for every row which i add on. I have used TableLayout for the container with these components in it.

Comment: Also, I tried reading the data from the table using the line findTbl(c).getValueAt(k,i) inside a nested loop, where k increments till the total nnumber of rows have been read in from, and i increments by 3 each time k increases by 1. However, the getValueAt() method gives me an error. How else can i read the data from the table container if this method isn't applicable? :)

Comment: That isn't clear to me. It said what you did (partially) not what you want to accomplish visually. If you set the table to scrollable I assume you want the rest to be fixed on the screen. So set the form to border layout. Place the table in the center and place a container with all other components in the south.